# How can get the value of all the keys in json array at 1st json element using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var resultJSON = [{"name":"AAA","createdDate":"8/14/2019"},{"name":"ABAB","_id":"52f0e7719c3fccfabfaaf5218bad7d22","createdDate":"8/14/2019"},{"name":"BBB","_id":"848e3d2fcedad749fa8dc22b97db663a","createdDate":"8/14/2019"}];

for (var k in resultJSON[0]);
alert(resultJSON[k]);
```

Comment: js manages **array objects**, there is nothing called *json array* in js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Object.keys()`:

```js
var resultJSON = [{"name":"AAA","createdDate":"8/14/2019"},{"name":"ABAB","_id":"52f0e7719c3fccfabfaaf5218bad7d22","createdDate":"8/14/2019"},{"name":"BBB","_id":"848e3d2fcedad749fa8dc22b97db663a","createdDate":"8/14/2019"}];
console.log(Object.keys(resultJSON[0]));
```